JsonValue to JsonString?
I struggle a bit with Jakarta's JSON processing. How to get the string of an element of an array?
import jakarta.json.*;

String str = "{ \"test\": [\"abc\", \"xyz\"], \"test2\": \"blabla\" }";
    
JsonReader jr = Json.createReader (new StringReader (str));
JsonObject jo = jr.readObject ();
    
JsonString js = jo.getJsonString("test2");
System.out.println(js.toString());      // OK - "blabla"
System.out.println(js.getString());     // OK - blabla
    
JsonValue jv = jo.getJsonArray ("test").get(0);
System.out.println (jv.toString());     // "abc"

// how to get abc instead of "abc"?


let me understand using getString()  is not an option ?  JsonArray ja = jo.getJsonArray("test");
JsonString arrayElement = (JsonString) ja.get(0);
System.out.println(arrayElement.getString()); // abc

Thanks, I did not know that I can cast that.

As mentioned in comment, we could cast the value to JsonString.
A better way is to use standard API JsonArray#getString(int).
import jakarta.json.*;

import java.io.StringReader;

public class JakartaJsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "{ \"test\": [\"abc\", \"xyz\"], \"test2\": \"blabla\" }";

        JsonReader jr = Json.createReader(new StringReader(str));
        JsonObject jo = jr.readObject();

        JsonString jv = jo.getJsonArray("test").getJsonString(0);
        System.out.println(jv.getString());     // abc
    }
}

